# Where is the grave of Johann Heinrich Lambert?

Tags: biography, famous-people

What is location of the grave of Johann Heinrich Lambert?

He was a Swiss-French mathematician, who lived between 1728-1777.

[Wikipedia: Johann Heinrich Lambert](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Heinrich_Lambert)

I tried a search on the [Find a Grave](https://www.findagrave.com/) website with no results.

Comment: Lambert was buried in the Huguenot cemetery in Berlin, today commonly referred to as the French Cemetery ("Französischer Friedhof"). It is not immediately clear whether his grave is still extant, as his name does not appear in lists of well-known personalities buried in this cemetery.

Comment: Correction: Französischer Friedhof I, Chausseestraße 127, 10115 Berlin, was created in 1780, so a few years *after* Lambert's death. I have not been able to establish where the previous Huguenot cemetery of Berlin was located; possibly in the churchyard of the French Church in Berlin (completed in 1705)? After searching for a couple hours, I can find no information on the Berlin Huguenot cemetery of 1777 or Lambert's grave, so I assume that neither exists today.

Comment: Another candidate would be the neighbouring [Dorotheenstadt cemetery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dorotheenstadt_Cemetery). It was opened in 1762, but none of the graves before 1807 have survived. As [de.wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedhof_der_Dorotheenst%C3%A4dtischen_und_Friedrichswerderschen_Gemeinden#Geschichte) points out, members of the Academies got burried there because if they were living nearby, they would have been members of the Dorotheenstadt parish (the church was half-owned by the French and the German parish.)

Comment: If you want to put in extra research effort, you might want to try contacting the French Reformed parish in Berlin to see whether they have any relevant information on Lambert. Their website is at https://www.franzoesische-kirche.de/de (in German only, best I can tell). They provide an email address for the person in charge of their cemeteries ("Kirchhöfe") under the "Kontakte" tab. Look for: "Verwaltung der Kirchhöfe".